# React Hooks dafault state generate null instead of empty array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I use Hooks useState and as default state I use an empty array.
The problem is only with **filteredList state**, when I load the page my state is null instead of empty array.
If I set an empty object or just a string, then it shows the real default state, but if i put there an array with values then first it logs the correct array, and then turns to an empty arary.
The weird thing is that it worked just fine few days ago when I wrote it, so I don't know if it's a quirk or a problem...
Here's my code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [inputText, setinputText] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
  const [filterStatus, setFilterStatus] = useState("all");
  const [filteredList, setFilteredList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
     getLocalTodos();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
     filterHandler();
     saveLocalTodos();
  }, [todos, filterStatus]);

  const filterHandler = () => {
     switch (filterStatus) {
        case "completed":
           setFilteredList(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === true));
           break;
        case "uncompleted":
           setFilteredList(todos.filter(todo => todo.completed === false));
           break;
        default:
           setFilteredList(todos);
           break;
        }
   }

   const saveLocalTodos = () => {
     localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
   }

   const getLocalTodos = () => {
     setTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')));
   }
```

And the rest is the return..

Comment: I believe you have a race condition in your code. Both of your effects run one after the other, one is trying to `get` the todos, the other is trying to `set` the todos.

Comment: Can you provide `return` code too for us to understand more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is in:

```
const getLocalTodos = () => {
  setTodos(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')));
}
```

Check the value stored in key 'todos' in localStorage

Comment: You're right , the value in local storage is null.
Why it sets null as value instead of just an empty array?
To solve this I entered a condition to saveLocalStorage(), that if todos state is empty than 'todos' in local storage will be [ ], else it will be equal to todos state ...
Not sure if that's the right approach.